# Write down an epimorphism from $F_{2}$ to the symmetric group $S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Write down an epimorphism from $F_{2}$ to the symmetric group $S_{3}$ and draw the covering graph of $R_{2}$ corresponding to the kernel K of the epimorphism. Hence determine the rank of the free group K.

What is a good way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A good way is to start by remembering what one needs to do to define a homomorphism from a free group.

Comment: The free group over two elements $a,b$ consists of all reduced words which are a product of $a $ and $b $, i.e. $a^{i_1}b^{i_2}\cdots b^{i_n}$ with exponents $i_1,i_2,...,i_n\in\mathbb {Z} $. We can define $S_3:=\langle d,s|d^3, s^2, dsds\rangle $. Now the surjective homomorphism should be obvious.

Comment: How do we find the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the epimorphism we just need to map the generators of $F_2$ to generators of $S_3$, which are $\{(1 2), (1 2 3)\}$.

Then $F_2/K$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, so the index of kernel $K$ is $[F_2 : K] = |S_3| = 6$. By Schreider index formula, $K$ is a free group of rank $7$.

I don't know how to directly determine the covering graph for the kernel but am really interested.